# Test Flight does not detect a new build with same version number

Tags: testflight

I already have a app on testflight with version number say 2.2.1 with permission to 3 users.

I now create another IPA with some minor changes, and upload the same to testflight with the exact same version number ( i cannot change the version# as this is an internal release).

The upload is successful, but it does not add the "#2" to the build version. Because of this the permissions page comes down with the 3 testers already selected.

The problem here now is, click " Update and notify" does not send emails to these 3 testers as they had been already given permissions for the previous build.

Any help on how i can force testflight to detect that this is a new build?

here's the reference for the feature.
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402778-how-version-numbers-are-set-

Comment: Same problem here. Longing for an answer...

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, the change is detected only if there is a change in the build/version. so i ended up using a date in the build no like x.x.20140322, so every time i create a new IPA, i change the date in the build no# and it works.

Answer (score 22):

I tried Alexey's approach and it did not work for me.

I did get it fixed by going to iTunesConnect: My Apps -> YourAppName -> Prerelease -> Builds

I then turned off the "TestFlight Beta Testing" switch and then turned it back on again.

[image: Here is a screenshot.]

Comment: Just had this issue and this worked nicely. Thx. The new build in TF kept saying to "invite testers" but the testers were already invited. Seems like toggling the TF beta testing switch unstuck the state of the new build and turned it active. It did not un-invite current testers for me incase you're concerned.

Comment: This worked for me. Strangely I got the notification for the new build right when I flipped the switch OFF.

Comment: "Turn it off, and then turn it back on." How often has that been my advice to non-tech-savvy folks? I should have followed my own advice.

Answer (score 4):

As noted previously, you cannot just upload a new binary with the same version number. Use a different version number. However, in my case (iOS 8.0.2) TestFlight app on the device could not see the newer version. No matter what I did on the device (e.g. uninstall/install again) the same version remained in TestFlight app.

The solution was to go to iTunesConnect, open Prelease->Internal testers tab, and DE-SELECT all existing testers (and Save). After that TestFlight app stopped showing this app on the device, and  finally, I could re-invite testers, and after accepting invitation the correct version of app appeared in TestFlight app.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. That doesn't seem right. Even if I'm changing the build number, it won't send notifications for the new build to my testers on the same version number? That's causes issues, since I can't create a new version until I submit this version to the App Store and I don't want to do that, since it has bugs that my new build fixes. Is this intended behavior?

Comment: I don't think that's intended behaviour, we just have to use this workaround before Apple fixes this...

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you can upload a new build with the same version.  I did observe that just uploading a new build does not trigger a notification to the TestFlight users.  However once I completed the "What to Test field" in the build information section all my users got their notification right away.

Comment: can you explain how is it that you uploaded a new build with the same version?.If I try to do that from XCode it gives: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exist a binary upload with build version '2.0' for train 2.0' at SoftwareAssets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset